# Android, DynamoDb, Document API, how to update item?

Tags: android, amazon-dynamodb

I'm playing around with Android and DynamoDb using the Document API:

```
com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.document.Table
```

I have a table with two attributes, Telephone (primary key) and name - both are Strings.

I can update the name attribute.

I am having trouble adding new attributes. This is the code I use:

```
 Document retrievedDoc = dbTable.getItem(new Primitive(telephone));
    if (retrievedDoc != null) {
        retrievedDoc.put("Telephone", "zzzzzzzzz");
        retrievedDoc.put("name", "Billy Bob");
        retrievedDoc.put("country", "USA");
        retrievedDoc.put("song","Ding Dong");

        Document result = dbTable.updateItem(retrievedDoc, new Primitive(telephone)
                , new UpdateItemOperationConfig().withReturnValues(ReturnValue.ALL_NEW));

        Log.i(TAG, "Update result: " + result);
        return true;

    }
```

Using the code like this successfully updates the item and adds the two new attributes (country and song). However if I don't include:

```
retrievedDoc.put("Telephone", "zzzzzzzzz");
```

Then only the name attribute is updated and neither of the two new attributes are added.

What is the correct way to update an item and add new attributes at the same time? I have Googled and read the (inadequate and sparse) relevant documentation but can't find a solution so any help will be appreciated.

Thanks